# Looking to RE a Ducky Shine 5

Tags: c++, firmware

I know how to program in C++/C# and a few other low level languages. I'm however in the dark about reverse engineering firmware etc. I was wondering if anyone could point me towards some learning tools etc to start me off? The help would be greatly appreciated!

Mostly looking for how to grab the firmware from the keyboard, how to analyse the resulting firmware (I read an article briefly on this subject but it didn't go into great detail) and how to then repackage the firmware to try it out on the keyboard.

Mostly this is a side project of sorts. Learning a new skill as well as attempting to create some custom profiles for the ducky shine 5s awesome RGB switches (the standard stuff is fun and all... but.. it would be nice to have customizability in there!)

Comment: A pair of presentations @ c3 may be relevant to get you started: [reverse engineering your kvm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47kZQ_4DgGo) and [hardsploit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYqeH47ATFQ) and